# Bootstrap modal close event in Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

How to handle bootstrap Modal in Angular 7

I have Form in Bootstrap Modal which I want to reset on modal close event (When clicked outside the modal), I Searched on Google but couldn't find anything

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please add some code to look at so we can try to help

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#component

Comment: Which angular-bootstrap lib are you using? Most of the lib will have the **backdrop** option to allow click outside to close or not. By default, most of the lib will have the value of **backdrop** is **true**. It means that the modal will be closed on click outside.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [@ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) you can do like this

First I have child component like this. This component will be a popup

```
export class DeleteInvoiceComponent implements OnInit {
  public confirmState = ConfirmState;
  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

And in the view

```
(click)="activeModal.close(confirmState.Ok)"
```

So in my parent component

```
import { NgbModal } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

 constructor(
    private modalService: NgbModal
  ) {}

public deleteInvoice(invoiceId: string): void {
    this.modalService.open(DeleteInvoiceComponent).result.then(result => {
      if (result === ConfirmState.Ok) {
        do some thing
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i can reset the model on click action of the modal but my concern is to reset the modal when it automatically hide if we click on anywhere on screen